# Problem with localizations in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

I'm working on a web application using C# that has to be localized. On my login.aspx page it does not seam to find the login.aspx.resx file. I have use Tools->Generate Local Resource for the page and every thing was working fine. But now for some reason it is not able to load the resource file.

In my code it calls GetLocalResourceObject("UserNotFound").ToString() and this is the exception I'm getting

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "login.aspx.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "App_LocalResources.root.vljjvu2t" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

So in the code behind and on the localized controls its just not seeing the resource file.

The problem seams weird. On my laptop it seams to be working fine but on my desktop its not. They are both using the same revision.

EDIT:

I managed to track it down to .NET being corrupted. If any one has any ideas on how to fix .net 3.5 install on Windows 7 it will be very helpful.

Comment: Does the rest of your site localize normally?

Comment: No the problems seams to be happening every where.

Answer (score 1):

How are you setting globalization?

Are you calling base.InitializeCulture(),  are you setting it manually in the web.config?

```
<globalization uiCulture="auto"/>
```

This tells the app to check the users culture settings in the browser.